# Python binary tree

Tags: python, class, binary-tree

I have implemented a simple tree and I have this problem. When I try to search for a node and it exists it returns None even though it runs the print at the if statement in lookup method. It runs ok when I lookup for the root node. All the rest nodes return None. Could someone explain why ?

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.data == data:
            print "this item exists"
        elif self.data > data:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        else:
           if self.right == None:
                self.right = Node(data)
           else:
                self.right.insert(data)

    def print_nodes(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_nodes()
        print self.data
        if self.right:
            self.right.print_nodes()

    def lookup(self,data):
        if self.data == data:
            print 'exists'
            return 1
        elif self.data > data:
            if self.left != None:
                self.left.lookup(data)
            else:
                return -1
        elif self.data < data:
            if self.right != None:
                self.right.lookup(data)
            else:
                return -1


    def delete(self,data):
        if self.lookup(data)== -1:
            print "doesnot exists"
        else:
            if (not self.left) and (not self.right):
                self.data = None

root = Node(5)
#root.insert(3)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(61)
root.insert(62)
root.insert(63)

x = root.lookup(3)
print x
```

Comment: You're not returning the results from the recursive calls to lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when the item is not exists in the root, you call to its sons `lookup()` functions without returning their value, so even if the code finds the data somewhere in the tree, you get `None` value instead of the result (`1`/`-1`)

Replace this lines:

```
self.left.lookup(data)
...
self.right.lookup(data)
```

with the lines:

```
return self.left.lookup(data)
...
return self.right.lookup(data)
```